# iOS 10.3.x device connection issue to Sierra Mac VM on Ubuntu 16.4/17.04

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, ubuntu, macos-sierra

I use Mac VM for iOS development on Ubuntu System.
After I upgrade iOS version from 10.2.1 up to 10.3.X, I can't connect my iOS devices to my Sierra Mac VM.
All iOS devices(iPod, iPhone, iPad) was connected without any issues before updates.
After iOS updates, Mac VM can't recognize device. And if I click connect USB device button or connect removable devices from VM menu, it shows "Unknown Error" message.
iTunes don't recognize iOS devices at all.
I tried to change USB controller of VM to 2.0 & 3.0. Not working.
But I can still connect all updated iOS devices with previous Mac versions (10.11.x). But here, I can't install XCode version 8.3 for updated iOS version devices. So with previous Mac versions, I can't develop.

I checked this on VMWare WorkStation 12.X and also Virtual Box. All are not working.

I think, current issue is because Sierra & Ubuntu.

Let me know if anybody resolve this issue.
Thank you.

Comment: Did you find a solution? I have exactly the same issue with Sierra 12.2, VMPlayer 12 and XCode 9. I tried compatibility settings for USB 2.0 and 1.1 to no avail.

Answer (score 1):

Issue was resolved by creating MacOS Sierra with following links:
http://www.tactig.com/install-macos-sierra-on-vmware/
I reinstall my Ubuntu and created Mac VM with above link.
Pls remember to update VMX file at last.

I thought my previous MacVM included issues.

All are working well with Sierra 10.12 on my side. But not tested for macOS High Sierra 10.13. Following is the link
http://www.tactig.com/download-install-macos-high-sierra-vmware/

Thanks.